# matrix manipulation SciLab

Tags: syntax, scilab

I heard there was some way to change matrix values without using the FOR loop. For example:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]
```

There is suppose to be a way I can make all the values for example less than 4 and changed them to some other value, let's say zero. Something like this:

```
A(...<4...)=0
```

And the answer should be:

```
 ans  =

0.    0.  
0.    4.
```

Anyone know the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use `find` for this; you can simply use indexing instead :

```
A(A>=4) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

A(find(A<4))=0;